# Search query - Searching multiple tables and columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database in which I return information about several entities in a single free text search, here is an example database:

**dbo.Electrician**

```
ElectricianId | Company     | TelNo     | Mobile   | Addr1        | Postcode
123           | Sparky 1    | 01234567  | 0789078  | 42 lower ave | Ex2345
124           | Sparky 2    | 01235678  | 0777777  | 1 Street     | Ta6547
125           | Sparky 3    | 05415644  | 0799078  | 4 Air Road   | Gl4126
```

**dbo.Painters**

```
PainterId     | Company     | TelNo     | Mobile   | Addr1        | Postcode
333           | Painter 1   | 01234568  | 07232444 | 4 Higher ave | Ex2345
334           | Painter 2   | 01235679  | 07879879 | 5 Street     | Ta6547
335           | Painter 3   | 05415645  | 07654654 | 5 Sky Road   | Gl4126
```

**dbo.Clients**

```
ClientId | Name            | TelNo     | Mobile   | Addr1        | Postcode
100333   | Mr Chester      | 0154 5478 | 07878979 | 9 String Rd  | PL41 1X
100334   | Mrs Garrix      | 0254 6511 | 07126344 | 10 String Rd | PL41 1X
100335   | Ms Indy Pendant | 0208 1154 | 07665654 | 11 String Rd | PL41 1X
```

My current method is working as such:

Create Temp Table (EntityId, DisplayName, LongName, EntityType)

Take search terms and replace unwanted characters before replacing spaces with commas and using this as a CSV.

```
SET @searchTerms = LTRIM(RTRIM(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
        REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@searchTerms)), ',', ' '),
        '[', ''),
        ']', ''),
        '#', ''),
        '&', ''),
        ';', ''),
        '?', ''),
        '`', ''),
        '''', ''),
        '*', ''),
        '"', ''),
        '<', ' '),
        '>', ' '),
        '-', ' '),
        '(', ' '),
        ')', ' '),
        '\', ' '),
        '/', ' ')))

        SET @searchTerms = REPLACE(@searchTerms, ' ', ',')

        DECLARE @SearchTerm AS nvarchar(50);

        DECLARE @DevelopmentCursor AS CURSOR;
        SET @DevelopmentCursor = CURSOR
        FOR
        SELECT
          *
        FROM general.Csvtoquery(@searchTerms)
        WHERE value != ''
```

Next I loop over my search terms inserting each entity into my Temp table:

```
            INSERT INTO #tempsearchtable (EntityId, Name, LongName, EntityType)
            SELECT
                tc.ClientId,
                tc.Title + ' ' + tc.FirstName + ' ' + tc.LastName,
                tc.Title + ' ' + tc.FirstName + ' ' + tc.LastName + ', ' + COALESCE(a.NameOrNumber, '') + ', ' + COALESCE(a.Street, '') + ', ' + COALESCE(a.Town, '') + ', ' + + ', ' + COALESCE(a.County, '') + ', ' + COALESCE(a.Postcode, '') + ', ' + COALESCE(a.Country, '')  + ', ' + COALESCE(tc.EmailAddress, '')  + ', ' + COALESCE(REPLACE(tc.Telephone, ' ', ''), '')  + ', ' + COALESCE(REPLACE(tc.Mobile, ' ', ''), ''),
                'Client'
            FROM 
                dbo.Clients tc
            LEFT JOIN 
                dbo.[Address] a ON tc.AddressId = a.AddressId
            WHERE 
                tc.FirstName LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
                OR tc.LastName LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
                OR tc.EmailAddress = @SearchTerm
                OR REPLACE(tc.Telephone, ' ', '') LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
                OR REPLACE(tc.Mobile, ' ', '') LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
                OR a.NameOrNumber LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
                OR a.Street LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
                OR a.Postcode LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
                OR a.County LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
                OR a.Town LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
                OR a.Country LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
```

I now loop my searches again. This is to ensure I am only getting specific matches. I delete anything where the LongName doesn't contain my search term.

I select all from the temp table before dropping it.

While this does work, and works pretty well, the search is slower than I'd like and I was looking for suggestions to speed this up. One of which was to create an index table and dump all the entities into this, and just have 1 loop getting the specific searches. This is slightly faster but it also means I only have data for when the last task was set to dump the data into the index. Live searches are imperative.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Gail Shaw has a great article about this type of catch all query here. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 0):

Some observations first:

- If your tables are the same in structure (as it looks here), it was better not to keep different tables but to keep them *all in one* with an additional column to set the "DataType".
- The column `Addr1` looks, as if you are keeping more than one address within your table. Whenever you feel the need to number a column's name (phone1, phone2), you should think about a related side table.

Back to your issue:

It looks as if you want to search within all column values whether a given string (or a list of given strings) is fullfilled

I do not know If I've got this completely correctly, but you might try this:

**Edit:** used wrong table name...

--Just two of your tables

```
DECLARE @tblElectrician TABLE(ElectricianId INT,Company VARCHAR(100),TelNo VARCHAR(100),Mobile VARCHAR(100),Addr1 VARCHAR(100),Postcode VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblElectrician VALUES
 (123,'Sparky 1','01234567','0789078','42 lower ave','Ex2345')
,(124,'Sparky 2','01235678','0777777','1 Street','Ta6547')
,(125,'Sparky 3','05415644','0799078','4 Air Road','Gl4126');

DECLARE @tblPainters TABLE(PainterId INT,Company VARCHAR(100),TelNo VARCHAR(100),Mobile VARCHAR(100),Addr1 VARCHAR(100),Postcode VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblPainters VALUES
 (333,'Painter 1','01234568','07232444','4 Higher ave','Ex2345')
,(334,'Painter 2','01235679','07879879','5 Street','Ta6547')
,(335,'Painter 3','05415645','07654654','5 Sky Road','Gl4126');
```

--The search terms (after your cleaning)

```
DECLARE @SearchTerms TABLE(LookFor VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @SearchTerms VALUES('Spar'),('78');
```

--The query will start with a `UNION` on the tables to get them as one. (This is actually the way this should be stored)

```
WITH UnionedData aS
(
    SELECT 'E' AS DataType, ElectricianId AS [Id],Company,TelNo,Mobile,Addr1,Postcode
    FROM @tblElectrician
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P',PainterId,Company,TelNo,Mobile,Addr1,Postcode
    FROM @tblPainters
) 
,AllValues AS
(
    SELECT a.*
          ,(
            SELECT b.* 
            FROM UnionedData AS b
            WHERE a.Id=b.Id
            FOR XML PATH('x'),TYPE
           ).query(N'data(/x/*)').value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Concatenated
    FROM UnionedData AS a
)
SELECT AllValues.*
FROM AllValues
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @SearchTerms AS st 
             WHERE AllValues.Concatenated LIKE '%' + st.LookFor + '%');
```

The intermediate result of the cte `AllValues` is this (only columns `Id` and `Concatenated`):

```
id     concatenated (all values as one string)
123    E 123 Sparky 1 01234567 0789078 42 lower ave Ex2345
124    E 124 Sparky 2 01235678 0777777 1 Street Ta6547
125    E 125 Sparky 3 05415644 0799078 4 Air Road Gl4126
333    P 333 Painter 1 01234568 07232444 4 Higher ave Ex2345
334    P 334 Painter 2 01235679 07879879 5 Street Ta6547
335    P 335 Painter 3 05415645 07654654 5 Sky Road Gl4126
```

The trick is to use XQuery's abilities to deal with generic data. First I create an XML of all columns with `SELECT *` and then I use `.query(N'data(/x/*)')`, which will return a list of all values separated by a blank.

With the final `SELECT` I use `EXISTS` to check, if there is at least one hit within the table `@SearchTerms`.

The final result (looking for *Spar* and *78*) will return all "Sparky" rows and "Painter 2", due to the Mobile number  with a "78"

Comment: Hi there. My tables aren't exactly the same. The addr1 was just an example and I have an address table which is keyed with an int. I have tried to index it as one string and it does slightly improve performance if the table is already done (in total I have over 2 million rows of data) - however actually putting every match into the table is cumbersome and not hugely fast.

Comment: @Dan However it will be possible, even with slightly different schema, to combine all results into one result set using `UNION`

Comment: @Dan If you have an addr table then why are you not using it consistently.  This data design looks like a mess to me.

Comment: I am using it consistently this was purely a simplified example

Comment: You are inserting into the same #temp so that you are using them for is them is the same.  Not buying.

Comment: What are you not buying sorry?

Comment: @Dan I don't get this *actually putting every match into the table is cumbersome* Such a search on 2 mio rows will not be rocket fast... It might be an idea to add a column (or to maintain a searchtable) where you permanently store the concatenated values. You can do this with a computed column or via trigger. Indexes won't help when you use `%` at the beginning with `LIKE`

Comment: @Dan Did you understand, that my approach does not need any temp tables, no loops and no procedural (repeated) actions? This is purely set based and *ad-hoc* SQL which should be faster than your approach. But it is heavy and quite expensive on the database server if this search is run more often.

Comment: I do now but I am now viewing on a phone so missed where you were going with it. My apologies!

Comment: @Dan take the time to check it out... It might be an idea to store the concatenated values permanently and then use *full text search*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be any faster, but have you tried creating one string and using LIKE on that one string?

Something like:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM 
  dbo.Clients tc
  LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.[Address] a ON tc.AddressId = a.AddressId
WHERE 
  REPLACE( tc.FirstName + '|' + tc.LastName + '|' + tc.EmailAddress + tc.Telephone + '|' + ....., ' ', '' ) LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
```

Considering that SQL is not that great with parsing, I wonder if the LIKE performs a lazy expression search that could make this approach faster than using a barrage of OR statements. The '|' Pipe signs are to prevent search terms like "jared" from matching a FirstName + LastName of "Jar Jar" "Edwards", etc.