# UNION and literal value, weird result

Tags: sql-server, union

Today I encountered something weird (or I'm to tired to see something obvious)

**Disclaimer:** No need to continue reading... Yes, I was to tired and this is nonsense...

SQL-Server: 11.0.6251.0

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50375610/5089204) and saw, that all rows got an "E" in the first place.

This is the same in short

```
DECLARE @tblA TABLE(Id INT,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES (1,'blah');

DECLARE @tblB TABLE(Id INT,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES (2,'blub');

SELECT 'A' AS SourceFlag, Id, SomeValue
FROM @tblA
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', Id, SomeValue
FROM @tblB
```

This I get back

```
SourceFlag  Id  SomeValue
A           1   blah
A           2   blub
```

Why didn't the second row get the "B"?

The execution plan:

[image]

One *Compute Scalar* shows *[Expr1004] = Skalaroperator('A')* the other one shows *[Expr1009] = Skalaroperator('B')*.

The *Concatenation* defines the result as *Union1010; Union1011; Union1012*, while *Union1010* is defined in *[Union1010] = (Expr1004; Expr1009); [Union1011] = (Id; Id); [Union1012] = (SomeValue; SomeValue)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No data was ever inserted into `@tblB`. ID 2 was inserted into `@tblA`.

```
DECLARE @tblB TABLE(Id INT,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES (2,'blub');
```

Comment: Oh my god! And I made the same mistake in the related question!!! To be honest: I would really love to delete this immediately (what a shame :-D), but in this case I could not pay you the points. Thx

Comment: Was just commenting the same thing. Well spotted.

Comment: @SeanLange If this was posted by somebody else and I was the first to visit the question, well, I think I'd check such things first :-D Our brain is weird actually...